# How to find and replace all files in a folder using a dynamic value

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a few html files where I need to add the pagename as a tag value. Plenty of tools to do mass find and replace, but than you are restricted to a static text, while I need to add the actual filename.

It works perfectly fine on a single file, but if I start to loop into a directory it goes wrong, and I'm not able to figure out where things go wrong.

Doing this on a single predefined file works as expected :

```batch
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion
rem Create tmp file to store modified information
set tmpFile=%CD%\test\tmp.txt
set myFile=%CD%\test\test.html
set page=test

rem delete current tmp file
if exist "%tmpFile%" del /f /q "%tmpFile%"

rem find and replace values
set search="container"
set replace="container_!page!"

rem loop through all the lines and replace the string in question
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%myFile%) do (
set myLines=%%a
set myLines=!myLines:%search%=%replace%!
echo !myLines!  >> %tmpFile%
)
rem update current file with updated content
type !tmpFile! > !myFile!
)
pause
```

The above nicely finds my string, and replaces it with the one I want (though still static in this case)

But if I want the same logic to loop through more files it goes wrong. This is the code I use :

```batch
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion
rem Create tmp file to store modified information
set tmpFile=%CD%\test\tmp.txt
rem switch to test folder
cd %CD%/test

rem Start the loop
For /R  %%F in (*.html) do (

rem get page name
set page=%%~nxF
set MyFile=%%F
rem delete current tmp file
if exist "%tmpFile%" del /f /q "%tmpFile%"

rem find and replace values
set search="container"
set replace="container_!page!"

rem loop through all the lines and replace the string in question
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%%F) do (
set myLines=%%a
set myLines=!myLines:%search%=%replace%!
echo !myLines!  >> %tmpFile%
)

rem update current file with updated content
type !tmpFile! > !myFile!

)

pause
```

This basically doesn't do anything, I've been trying some otehr variations but these result in either empty pages or pages that contain myLines= as a literal string.

What am I overlooking here ?

[EDITED AREA]

I've managed to get it working partially, but have strange unwanted side effects.

Not using search / replace parameters but using it directly in the replace parts as follows works :

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%%F) do (
set myLines=%%a
set "myLines=!myLines:container=container_%%~nF!"
echo !myLines!  >> %tmpFile%
)
```

This replaces container with container_pagename as I wanted , BUT it also removes all esclamation marks on my htm, which is quite annoying, as it ruins all the comments on the page.

```
so <!-- comment -->
becomes <-- comment -->
```

Any clue where it goes wrong, or why using parameters doesn't work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
type !inputfile! > !tmpFile!
```

might be a problem. Suggest you consider what it does...

I'd also change

```
set var="value"
```

to

```
set "var=value"
```

The first assigns a quoted value to `var`; the second ensures that stray spces on the line are not included in `value` assigned to `var`

Comment: Thanks for spotting,  bad copy paste from my side. The type line basically copies the tmp content to the original file.